# Where to keep my assets i.e. images?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In my firemonkey project, Where I am supposed to keep my assets i.e. images and how to set them as my Buttons background images?

Comment: It depends on the platform. Although if you're doing multi-platform, you're better off embedding them inside your app, for example in an image list, or as resource files. Bear in mind, depending on the size of your images, this will also slow down the speed of your app startup.

Comment: Can you provide these two important pieces of information? a) Specific platform(s) you're targeting, and b) Are all images the same size? Also, "how to set them as my Button background images" is a separate question. Once you get your answer to this one, you can ask your other question separately.

Comment: You don't mention which version of Delphi you are using. This is quite important as Firemonkey has evolved a lot. For example early versions of Firemonkey notoriously did not have a TImageList component. Please also clarify what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean you want to dynamically load your images and are wondering which directory to keep them in? Or you just want fixed images to appear on your buttons?